# Error: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

new to django
django version : Django==2.2
getting below error :
Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

while running below commands:

```
python3.7 manage.py collectstatic 

python3.7 manage.py shell 

python3.7 manage.py runserver
```

below is what my INSTALLED_APPS look like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'actions.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'common.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'hotels.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'extranet.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'communication.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'bulk_uploader.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'registration.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'channel_manager.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'reports.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'mobile.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'admin_shortcuts',
    'guardian',
    'actstream',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'oauth2app',
    'ckeditor',
    'stats',
    'django_celery_beat',
)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: The order of installed apps is important. Put django's own apps before others.

Comment: hi. @markwalker_ 
tried with 
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'actions.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'common.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'hotels.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'extranet.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'communication.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'bulk_uploader.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'registration.apps.MyAppConfig'}
still th same error

Comment: Have you ran all your migrations?